# c++ select issue

Tags: c++, select, asynchronous

So I'm trying to build a async server... Here is a summary of what I have so far:

```
int sockfd;
int max;
fd_set socks;
set<int> conns;

bind();
listen(sockfd);

while(1){
    FD_ZERO(&socks);
    max = sockfd;
    FD_SET(sockfd, &socks);
    for(set<int>::iterator it=conns.begin(); it!=conns.end(); it++){
        FD_SET(*it, &socks);
        if(max < *it){
            max = *it;
        }
    }

    int res = select(max+1, &socks, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(res < 0){
        cerr << "ERROR with select" << endl;
        break;
    }else if(res){
        if(FD_ISSET(sockfd, &socks)){
            //new connection
            int new_sockfd = accept();
            conns.insert(new_sockfd);
        }else{
            for(set<int>::iterator it=conns.begin(); it!=conns.end(); it++){
                if(FD_ISSET(*it, &socks){
                    char buffer[256];
                    read(buffer, 256, *it);
                    cout << buffer << endl;
                    close(*it);
                    conns.erase(*it);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What ends up happening is... If I connect a client-1, and then client-2. And then I try and send data using Client-2 and then Client-1... it works...

However, If I connect client-1 and then connect client-2... and then try to send data using client-1. Select() returns a -1...

Help?

Comment: what is the value of errno when select returns -1?

Comment: Is this homework, or maybe a learning exercise? You might find it easier to use a library like [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html).

Comment: @Sam: It's a learning exercise. I dislike relying on Boost so much... I feel like I don't understand it as well as I should.

Comment: @VJo: How do I look at errno?

Comment: @Andrew http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno

Comment: @VJo: errno is 9. Whats the best way to figure out what that means?

Comment: @Andrew: The easiest thing to do is: `if (res < 0) { perror("Select failed"); }`, this will print a useful error message. Otherwise, you can do this: `printf("Select failed: %s", strerror(errno));`

Comment: @Andrew `#define EBADF 9 /* Bad file number */` So, my guess was right.

Comment: @DarkDusk: I didn't know you could do that... Thanks!

Comment: @VJo: Yeah. Somehow me closing them that way was causing issues. I'm not 100% sure why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into [man pages for select](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select). The important part is :

Under the following conditions, pselect() and select() shall fail and set errno to:
**EBADF**
One or more of the file descriptor sets specified a file descriptor that is not a valid open file descriptor.
**EINTR**
The function was interrupted before any of the selected events occurred and before the timeout interval expired.

If SA_RESTART has been set for the interrupting signal, it is implementation-defined whether the function restarts or returns with [EINTR].
**EINVAL**
An invalid timeout interval was specified.
**EINVAL**
The nfds argument is less than 0 or greater than FD_SETSIZE.
**EINVAL**
One of the specified file descriptors refers to a STREAM or multiplexer that is linked (directly or indirectly) downstream from a multiplexer.

errno should tell you what is wrong.

This is just a quess, but when you close the connection, your file descriptor becomes invalid. I guess the error from select should be `EBADF`

Comment: Sure enough! Once I stopped closing that socket, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew: You may (and should) close the socket once you're done with it, but then you must not put it into the FD_SET.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code erasing from the set is suspect. once you call `conns.erase(*it)`, your iterator is invalid (and incrementing it leads to undefined behavior).

Changing your loop to something like the following should resolve the issue:

```
for(set<int>::iterator it=conns.begin(); it!=conns.end();)
{
    set<int>::iterator cur = it++;
    if(FD_ISSET(*cur, &socks)){
        char buffer[256];
        read(buffer, 256, *cur);
        cout << buffer << endl;
        close(*cur);
        conns.erase(*cur);
    }
}
```